# android onClick Button inside fragment not work and no errors

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I created a fragment with some buttons and I'm trying to call other fragment by clicking on the button but nothing happens, no errors, no actions.

This is my implementation:

main_activit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mainToobar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:title="@string/mainToobarTitle"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/homebuttons_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

HomeButtonsFragment.java

```
public class HomeButtonsFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_buttons, container, false);

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.schedule_home_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ScheduleFragment scheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_container, scheduleFragment);
    }
}
```

fragment_home_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/schedule_home_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/label.home.button.schedule"
        android:tag="home_button"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        style="@style/ScheduleButton"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: write a log message or show toast in your onClick method to see if onClick isn't called or there's problem with changing fragment code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss `.commit()` in your `fragmentTransaction` statement.

```
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_container, scheduleFragment).commit();
```

Comment: as a side note, doing fragment management inside a fragment is dubious at best.  it mostly defeats the purpose of fragments, which is to support multiple layouts and re-use.  typically, activities should do fragment managment.

Answer (score 0):

u missed **commit();**,i am sure small things will be missed sometimes,just add **commit();** , it will work fine 
use this
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

```
        ScheduleFragment scheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_container, scheduleFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

```
    ScheduleFragment scheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_container, scheduleFragment).commit();
```

**or**
fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

Answer (score -1):

Your onClick method should be,

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.schedule_home_button){
           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

           ScheduleFragment scheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();
           fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_container, scheduleFragment).commit();
        }
    }
```